# mysql workbench - Couldn't find option to remove DROP TABLE IF EXIST

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench, drop-table

Recently I've been looking into export options to find an option to remove:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` and replace it with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

I've seen on other MySQL clients like [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) or [sequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) (for MAC) where you can tick a option to include drop table or not, but couldn't find any related thing in the MySQL Workbench.

It's very dangerous as usually when exporting and importing to exchange data with other tables, it simply **DROPS** tables when they exist rather then just updating them.

I've did research about the issue, and all I'm getting is an explanation about drop table method itself.

I've been using MySQL Workbench for quite sometime, and now I'm really thinking to switch to another MySQL client because of this.

Im using MySQL Workbench Community edition version 8.0.12.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a limitation of MySQL Workbench, but one of `mysqldump` (which is used by Workbench to create the data export). See also [Create table if not exists from mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220469/create-table-if-not-exists-from-mysqldump).

Comment: I see, so seems that it can be an advantage and disadvantage.
I guess i'll have to resort to checking every sql file before importing (so it doesent drop tables when i dont want it to). Thanks